# Jupyter shell assignment passing variables to !sed

Tags: shell, sed, jupyter-notebook

This example works properly to find and replace from a Jupyter cell:

```
all_labels = ['cat', 'dog'] 
!sed -i 's/num_classes: 90/num_classes: {len(all_labels)}/g' {FILE_PATH}
```

However this  example with the same syntax produces an error:

```
record_path = '/path/to/data.record'
!sed -i 's/PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED\/mscoco_train\.record/{record_path}/g' {FILE_PATH}
```

I added two forward slashes to escape the backslash and period so my regex tester would recognize the sentence. The error I get is:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 50: unknown option to `s'

Anyone know why I can pass a variable in the first example, but not in the second?

Comment: Don't think this is entirely a duplicate as that post mentions nothing about how to do this easily with python or jupyter shell assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up needing to escape the variable too

```
import re
record_path = re.escape(record_path)
```